# How do I stop Firefox from closing my streaming jQuery ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, streaming, comet

I'm a little new to [comet](/questions/tagged/comet)-esque requests, so please speak up if I'm making too much work for myself and should be using a library or some other method.

Basically this is my situation: I have a page that sets an `<iframe>` element's `src` attribute to a [php](/questions/tagged/php) script. The PHP script streams the response with the following headers:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace
```

This works famously in [safari](/questions/tagged/safari)! However, [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) closes the connection after a couple of seconds. How do I fix this? I've examined the responses for the script for both browsers and the responses are identical otherwise (up to the point that Firefox closes the connection.)

**Awesome update**: Firefox hates the "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace". Once this is removed it works in Firefox.

Isn't there a better way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: You should answer your own question if you found a working solution, and accept the answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, cause now I see this damn question everytime I view unanswered...

Comment: Patience, patience, lads. I fully intend to accept my own answer. I was hoping to give folks the opportunity to provide better solutions for a spell before doing so.

Comment: And I really don't think a downvote was necessary. That's just silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to send `Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace` to Safari but not to Firefox.

For reasons I don't fully understand, Firefox will disconnect from the server after a few seconds if this header is present in the response. Firefox will handle a streaming response just fine otherwise.

To implement this, I simply added a check for the user agent in the code as such:

```
if( preg_match("/Safari/", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) )  
    header("Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace");
```